# swift global variable string came back nil

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, var

Having trouble to call value stored in global variable in Swift 4
here is the code look like

```
var coord : String!

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = (manager.location?.coordinate)!
    print("Locations : \(locValue.latitude), \(locValue.longitude)")

    let lat: String = String(format:"%f", locValue.latitude)
    let lon: String = String(format:"%f", locValue.longitude)
    let node = lat + "," + lon
    self.coord = node
    print("Coordinate", node)
    }
```

and then I tried to call it in another function,

```
func getAddress(){
    let location = coord
}
```

but it came back as `nil`
can anyone tell me what am I missing here

Comment: I think before didUpdateLocations called you are calling  getAddress method

Comment: Did you checked Coord after when you inputs a value in It ? try printing it once for reference that do value actually exist or placed in it or not ? and when are you calling getAddress method make sure is called after your value is updated

Answer (score 0):

you have to allocate memory for coord variable. like,

var coord = String()

Comment: This is not Objective-C and this is not the reason.

Comment: i know this is not Objective-C. but if u want to assign value to another then that variable must have to assign a memory, otherwise value is not assigned.

Comment: In Swift declaring a variable as implicit unwrapped optional and later assigning a value to is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
 let node = lat + "," + lon
 let stringValue:String = node as! String
 self.coord = stringValue
```

Answer (score -1):

I think its because you have not allocated Memory for "coord" thats why its comming null. so do one thing just before assing the value to "coord" allocate memory for it...Hope it helps..Thanks

Comment: This is not Objective-C and this is not the reason.